How to share a HashMap state amongst Yew Rust components?
I want to use a State hook wrapped around a HashMap to share the locations of Yew components. This is so that when each component is drawn and its position is set, another component will be notified (to draw lines between the components).
This is a broken example.
The idea is that on_ref_update will be called each time a component's position changes. This will set values in the HashMap, and this will be used to notify a listener (the connections component). I have left out the components with positions for brevity.
From what I have read this is the typical way to do it, but I get the compiler errors:

Type mismatch [E0308] expected HashMap<String, Element>, but found UseStateHandle<HashMap<String, Element>>
Cannot move

But as I understand from another question (How to get the value from state in Yew Rust) I should just dereference other_node_positions to get the state's value.
#[function_component(Pane)]
pub fn pane(PaneProps { some_prop }: &PaneProps) -> Html {
    let other_node_positions: UseStateHandle<HashMap<String, Element>> = use_state(|| HashMap::new());

    let on_ref_update = {
        let mut other_node_positions =  &other_node_positions;
        Callback::from(move |(id, element): (String, Element)| {
            other_node_positions.set({
                other_node_positions.insert(id, element);
                *other_node_positions
            });
        })
    };
    

    html! {
        <div>
            <Connections node_positions={Rc::clone(&other_node_positions)} />
        </div>
    }
}


There are several issues with your example:

Your state is of type HashMap<_, _> but you want to pass it as a Rc<HashMap<_, _>> to a child component via Rc::clone(&_).
You pass &other_node_positions, which is borrowed data, to a Callback that may outlive other_node_positions.
You attempt to move out of a UseStateHandle containing a non-Copy type via *other_node_positions.

Here is one way to solve these issues:
#[function_component(Pane)]
pub fn pane() -> Html {
    // Fix #1 by adding `Rc<_>` to state type.
    let other_node_positions: UseStateHandle<Rc<HashMap<String, Element>>> = use_state(|| Rc::new(HashMap::new()));

    let _on_ref_update = {
        // Fix #2 by cloning the `UseStateHandle`.
        let other_node_positions =  other_node_positions.clone();
        Callback::from(move |(id, element): (String, Element)| {
            // Fix #3 by cloning the `HashMap<_, _>` inside the `Rc<_>` state.
            let mut map = (**other_node_positions).clone();
            map.insert(id, element);
            other_node_positions.set(Rc::new(map));
        })
    };

    html! {
        <div>
            <Connections node_positions={Rc::clone(&other_node_positions)} />
        </div>
    }
}


Your implementation has a few issues stemming from how UseStateHandle works in Yew. Specifically, you cannot directly mutate the state handle because it represents an immutable reference to the state. Instead, you need to work with a cloned version or replace the state entirely.
Here's how to address the problem:
Key Changes to Fix the Code:

Clone the HashMap inside use_state before making changes.

Use .set on the state to update it with a new version.
Here's a corrected implementation:
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;
use web_sys::Element;
use yew::prelude::*;

#[derive(Properties, PartialEq)]
pub struct PaneProps {
    pub some_prop: String,
}

#[function_component(Pane)]
pub fn pane(PaneProps { some_prop }: &PaneProps) -> Html {
    // Initialize state for node positions
    let other_node_positions = use_state(|| HashMap::<String, Element>::new());

    // Define the callback for updating the reference
    let on_ref_update = {
        let other_node_positions = other_node_positions.clone(); // Clone state handle
        Callback::from(move |(id, element): (String, Element)| {
            // Clone the current map, update it, and replace the state
            let mut updated_positions = (*other_node_positions).clone();
            updated_positions.insert(id, element);
            other_node_positions.set(updated_positions);
        })
    };

    html! {
        <div>
            <Connections node_positions={(*other_node_positions).clone()}/>
        </div>
    }
}



What are the changes in this?

Cloning other_node_positions:


The use_state hook gives you an immutable handle. You must .clone() it when capturing it in the move closure to avoid ownership issues.


Creating a new HashMap:


Since UseStateHandle doesn't allow mutation, you create a new HashMap by cloning the current one, then update it, and finally replace the state with .set.


Dereferencing other_node_positions:


The state handle wraps the actual HashMap, so you dereference it with * to get the inner value and clone it when necessary.


Hi Taytaybear. It looks to me like you created this answer in part or whole by using an AI assistant (such as ChatGPT). Note that posting content generated by AI assistants is not allowed on Stack Overflow. Read more about this policy here. Please delete this answer if you've generated it using an AI assistant. Thank you.

Regardless of how this answer was created, the efficiency is sub-optimal since the Rc was removed, forcing the HashMap<_, _> to be cloned once per mutation and once when it is passed as a property.
